# Python Dataframe and Multi processing using shared dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing, pool

I have around 300 Million rows data  [Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GRwq.png).

For each distinct value of  column "A", i will get complete data when I merge the different tags "m", "m2","m3" of column "B".

My Approach:
I maintain a dictionary as follows:
{'d1': {'m3': 45, 'm': 0, 'm2': 23}, 'd2': {'m3': 47, 'm': None, 'm2': None}}

whenever I find all the three tags from column "B", for a distinct column "A", I write it back to the data frame. and save the row Number(which has "m" tag in column "B". here it is index 0). and write then write all those rows into new data frame.

But the issue here is 300 Million rows. I want to use shared dictionary and list to keep track of the above mentioned calculations using multi processing.

I'm using python 3. Any suggestions on how to do this is helpful. Thank you.

[Sample Output DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7287.png)

Sample output dataframe  may look like the picture.

Comment: Your description is really confusing. Your input DataFrame has 3 rows with `A == d1`. How do you want to merge them?

Comment: I want to copy the value of column "C" from row which has B== m2 and the value of column "E" from the row which has B == m3 @MikeHenderson